# Freeing AVPlayer Layer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using `UIPageViewController` for displaying some videos. Each view controller inside of my `UIPageViewController` contains an `AVPlayerLayer` with its movie. The problem is that right now it is wasting too much memory, so I'd like to keep the current one (the one that is being shown on the screen) the previous and the next one. The other videos should be freed. I tried assigning my `AVPlayerLayer` to nil but it is not working.
Another problem that I've got is that sometimes I get a black screen, it looks that the video is still running but it is now being shown.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Use a UIView subclass with the  AVPlayerLayer and add this as subview to the Page only when it is brought to front. Reuse this Player

Comment: The problem is that when I go back to the view controller the looks that the video wasn't freed, so I'm still expending much memory.

Comment: Are you using [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];

Comment: You mean self.player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil) is not possible in swift?

Comment: Sorry, it did allow me to do it, I'm going to check it now

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with swift. But heres a great work you can refer https://github.com/piemonte/Player